# How to Submit an HTML Form to a Google Forms using App Script?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form that is connected to a Google Sheet to collect the answers. In my form I have a field that is supposed to be a dropdown list but I need the content of the dropdown to be adapted to the user that fills in the form. That is why I created an HTML form with App Script that is exactly the same than the Google Form except the dropdown (it is a dropdown in the HTML form, updated according to the user with some javascript code, and a short text answer in the Google Form).

I'm trying to understand how can I submit the input values of my HTML form into a response to my GoogleForm.

It has to be to my google form and not directly into my google sheets because I need to have the edit url that google form creates and I want my user to be able to access it.
I'm precising that I have fields that are datepickers, file uploads, checkboxes...

How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you show some of your code and the html?

Comment: @aNewb what part ? because it is VERY long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the `FormApp` service

Here is a short example:

- I created a form with 2 "Short Answers".
- I want to create a response with Apps Script that responds with "Hello" to the first one and "World" to the second one.
- I opened the script editor of the form itself and used this code:

```js
function createResponse() {
  // Get the form this script is bound to
  let form = FormApp.getActiveForm()

  // Get the question items from the form
  let items = form.getItems()
  let item1 = items[0]
  let item2 = items[1]

  // Create a new form response
  let newResponse = form.createResponse();

  // Before making an ItemResponse, the items need to be cast as text types
  // Not sure why this is necessary, since they are already text types...
  // Not doing it results in an error
  let item1asText = item1.asTextItem()
  let item2asText = item2.asTextItem()

  // Creating each item response
  let itemResponse1 = item1asText.createResponse("Hello")
  let itemResponse2 = item2asText.createResponse("World")

  // Adding the item responses to the form response
  newResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse1)
  newResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse2)
  
  // Submitting the form response
  newResponse.submit()
}
```

#### Process explained for your HTML form

- Get all `items` from your form.
- Create a **form** response
- For Each item

  - Cast it as its appropriate type (e.g. `asTextItem()`, `asMultipleChoiceItem()` etc.)
  - Create an **item** response based on what you get from the HTML form. Most seem to take a string as an argument, but check the docs in case.
  - Add the item response to the form response
- Submit the form.

#### References

- [Form Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse())
- [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withItemResponse(ItemResponse))
- [Item Types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item)
- [ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response)

Comment: It works more than perfectly with most of Item Types, but do you know how can I pass files that I'd like to upload through the form ? @iansedano

Comment: Ah, files are more complicated, I wouldn't be able to answer that in a comment, and adapting my answer would make it too long. Plus you didn't mention files in your original question. Best best would be to open a new question specifically about that. I don't think it will be 100% clean, but there is definitely a workaround depending on what you need it for exactly.

Comment: I actually did mention that I have files upload... I'll open a new question about that specifically. Anyway thank you, it really helped me !